# Serre presentations over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-k-theory, kac-moody-algebras

Given a Cartan matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in I}$, a classical result of J.-P. Serre asserts that the complex semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak g(A)$ corresponding to $A$ admits a presentation with generators $e_i,f_i,h_i$ ($i\in I$) and relations ($*$) as follows:
\begin{align}
&[h_i,h_j]=0, \quad [h_i,e_j]=a_{ij}e_j, \quad [h_i,f_j]=-a_{ij}f_j, \quad [e_i,f_j]=\delta_{ij}h_i\quad\textrm{for all $i,j\in I$,}\\
&(\mathrm{ad} e_i)^{|a_{ij}|+1}e_j=0=(\mathrm{ad} f_i)^{|a_{ij}|+1}f_j\quad\textrm{for all $i,j\in I$ with $i\neq j$.}
\end{align}
Denote by $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb{Z}}$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ generated (as a $\mathbb{Z}$-Lie algebra) by the $e_i,f_i,h_i$ ($i\in I$).

Is it known whether ($*$) also defines a presentation of $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb{Z}}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$?

For instance:

(1) If $A=\bigg(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-1&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\bigg)$, then $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}_4(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathfrak{sl}_4(\mathbb{Z})$. Does ($*$) define a presentation of $\mathfrak{sl}_4(\mathbb{Z})$?

More generally:

(2) If $A=\bigg(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\bigg)$ (this time, a generalised Cartan matrix), then the (derived) affine Kac-Moody algebra $\mathfrak g$ defined by the presentation ($*$) is $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}])\oplus\mathbb{C}$ (a one-dimensional central extension of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}])$), and $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. Does ($*$) define a presentation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])\oplus\mathbb{Z}$?

If this is known, I would ideally be interested in a (reference to a) conceptual (not case-dependent) proof.

Comment: There's a long paper trail here, which I'll try to fill in later today if I have time.     Probably Chevalley was the first, though his Bourbaki seminar talk was flawed.     Then some Russians got active in working over $\mathbb{Z}$, and ultimately Lusztig got involved too.     Plus some contributions from people looking at quantized enveloping algebras and/or Kac-Moody Lie algebras.

Comment: In case this hasn't been done, there are some results (over an arbitrary ring) which might reduce to (a) understanding presentations of the subalgebras restricted to those weights on which some linear form is positive, (b) understanding central extensions in degree zero (i.e. computing $H_2$), for which there's an abundant literature. Namely, see Chapters 8-9 , especially Chap 9 "Abels' multiamalgam" of [my work with Tessera](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5373).

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the reference. However, I am not sure how it could be put to good use: my impression is that the problem amounts to deciding whether $\mathfrak{n}^+_{\mathbb{Z}}$ (the $\mathbb{Z}$-Lie subalgebra generated by the $e_i$) is the quotient of the free Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the $e_i$ by the ideal of Serre relations $(\mathrm{ad} e_i)^{|a_{ij}|+1}e_j$ (in other words, whether this quotient is torsion-free). I don't really see how your amalgamation Theorem 9.C.2 could be applied non-trivially to $\mathfrak{n}^+_{\mathbb{Z}}$...

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I refer to as (a). I said it's a reduction to (a) and (b), not that it bypasses them. I guess (a) can be done by hand in your examples.

Comment: @YCor Ok thanks, I understand now. I am actually interested in the question for arbitrary (say simply laced) generalised Cartan matrices, whence the last sentence in my question.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Thank you for your comment. Could you point to more precise references?